# Where to set state when I need that state in render?

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

I am getting this error below:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:2430 Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
```

From the error, I know I am getting it because I am setting state in the render.

But I am not sure where to set the state because I need that state element, `developerTitle` further down inside the render method.

Where can I put it if not in render?

Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
export default class Game extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            developerTitle: ''
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { indieDeveloperId } = this.props;
        this.setState({ developerTitle: this.getDeveloperTitle(game.indieDeveloperId) });
        
            <div>

                <h3>{this.state.developerTitle}</h3>
                ...
                ...
            </div>
    }
    
    //by-indie-developer/{indieDeveloperId
    async getDeveloperTitle(indieDeveloperId) {
        const r = await axios.get(`/api/developer/by-indie-developer/${indieDeveloperId}`);
        const developerTitle = r.data;
        this.setState({
            ...this.state, ...{
                developerTitle: developerTitle
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to set the state as soon as the component mounts?

Comment: If you set the state inside the render, it will cause it to re-render again, which in turn will set the state again and cause it to re-render, which in turn will set the state again and.... And that's the problem. 

You should use lifecycle methods to set the state, i.e. ```componentDidMount``` or ```componentDidUpdate```

Comment: @TheodorPeifer well as soon as I can, but it needs to call the `getDeveloperTitle` function first to get the title

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell call onMount and render your content with some condition based on `developerTitle` content

Comment: like `{ this.state.developerTitle && <div><h3>{this.state.developerTitle}</h3></div> }`

Comment: @buzatto is onMount like componentDidMount?

Comment: yes you call `componentDidMount` but only `this.getDeveloperTitle(this.props.game.indieDeveloperId)`, since you update the state inside the function already

Comment: @buzatto I am not sure if `componentDidMount` is working because when I put it in there, it tells me that `indieDeveloperId ` is undefined.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell then that means that you are not receiving on mount that prop, but on some update. then you would use `componentDidUpdate` instead. You could also at your parent conditional render `Game` component when you have that prop, since it seems `Game` component should only render when that prop is available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set a state in `render()`. But you can set a state when the component is loaded using the `componentDidMount()` function.
Add a function with that name like this to your component:

```js
componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ developerTitle: this.getDeveloperTitle(game.indieDeveloperId) });
}
```

You dont have to call the function. The state will automatically be set.

Comment: yes that's correct approach. just to notice, if you take a look `getDeveloperTitle` is async and already updates state inside. so it should be only `this.getDeveloperTitle(game.indieDeveloperId)`

Comment: it is telling me that `indieDeveloperId ` is undefined.  But when I put a `console.log("indieDeveloperId: ", indieDeveloperId);`  inside my `render`, I do see the correct value of `indieDeveloperId `.  Maybe `componentDidMount()` is being called before my `render`?